# Time Base, assembler, PIC , propeller clock

Tags: assembly, time, pic

So, I'm doing a propeller clock and it should display the hour and one name, using assembler and the [PIC 18F4550](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en010300). I think everything is fine. It's just that I can't manage to "make" a right time base.

The PIC works naturally at 8 MHz.

What I'm trying to do is to create a routine that counts 1 min, after that, the clock will add 1 minute to the "minutes", and so on (that part is done).

The user will set the hour, with 4 push buttons, and after that they set the current hour, and press the final push button. That's when the time base will kick in.

I think I can't do the last part, I just need help with the time base, because I can't seem to understand this in assembler (in C# I'd just do a bid while o do while or maybe a for).

One way I see this - maybe I just need to make a big delay - one that lasts 60 seconds - but I can put that in assembler language, or am I wrong?

Thank you in advance guys.
Here's the code for the clock:

```
LIST P = 18f4550    
#include<p18f4550.inc> 

CONFIG WDT = OFF    
CONFIG MCLRE = ON   
CONFIG DEBUG = OFF    
CONFIG LVP = OFF   
CONFIG FOSC = INTOSC_EC

Delay1 EQU 0x00    
Delay2 EQU 0x01 
AUX1   EQU 0x02
AUX2   EQU 0x03

ORG 0

MOVLW b'01110111'   ;8 MHz 
MOVWF OSCCON


CLRF PORTA
CLRF PORTB
CLRF TRISB
CLRF AUX1
CLRF AUX2

;MOVWF b'01100100'
;MOVLW AUX1

TEST
BTFSS PORTA,4
GOTO TEST
GOTO MainLoop  

MainLoop
MOVLW b'00000001'
ADDWF AUX2,1
CALL K
CALL retardo
CALL RE
CALL retardo
CALL O
CALL retardo
CALL NN
CALL retardo
CALL O
CALL retardo
CALL SS
CALL retardo
CALL MM
CALL retardo
CALL YY
CALL retardo
CALL GG
CALL retardo
 ;MOVWF b'01100100'
  MOVLW b'00000011'
 CPFSEQ AUX2,1
 GOTO MainLoop
 CALL OPT
 GOTO TEST

  ;*******************LETTERS**************** 

K
MOVLW b'11111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
call retardo
MOVLW b'00010100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00100010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01000001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN


RE
MOVLW b'01111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01001100'
MOVWF PORTB
call retardo
MOVLW b'01001100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00110011'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL  retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN

NN
MOVLW b'01111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00100000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00010000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000100'
MOVWF PORTB 
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN


O
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00010100'
MOVWF PORTB
call retardo
MOVLW b'00100010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01000001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00100010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00010100'
MOVWF PORTB
call retardo
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo 
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN

SS
MOVLW b'00010001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00101010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01000100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN

MM
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVlW b'00000100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVlW b'00000100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN


YY
MOVLW b'00000001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'01111000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN


GG
MOVLW b'01111001'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00101010'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00010100'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
MOVLW b'00001000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo 
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
RETURN

OPT
MOVLW b'11111111'
MOVWF PORTB
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CALL retardo
CLRF AUX2
MOVLW b'00000000'
MOVWF PORTB
RETURN

 ;*******NUMBER************

 HORAS1 
BTFSC PORTA,0
GOTO CERO1

CERO1
    BTFSC PORTA,0
    GOTO UNO1
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo



UNO1
    BTFSC PORTA,0
    GOTO CERO1
    MOVLW b'00010000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00100001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo




HORAS2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO CERO2

CERO2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO UNO2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo



UNO2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO DOS2
    MOVLW b'00010000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00100001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

DOS2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO TRES2
    MOVLW b'00110011'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000101'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01110001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo


TRES2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO CUATRO2
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

CUATRO2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO CINCO2
    MOVLW b'01111000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

CINCO2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO SEIS2
    MOVLW b'01111001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

SEIS2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO SIETE2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


SIETE2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO OCHO2
    MOVLW b'01000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


OCHO2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO NUEVE2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


NUEVE2
    BTFSC PORTA,1
    GOTO CERO2
    MOVLW b'00110001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


MINUTOS1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO CEROM1

CEROM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO UNOM1
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo



UNOM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO DOSM1
    MOVLW b'00010000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00100001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

DOSM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO TRESM1
    MOVLW b'00110011'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000101'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01110001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo


TRESM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO CUATROM1
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

CUATROM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO CINCOM1
    MOVLW b'01111000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

CINCOM1
    BTFSC PORTA,2
    GOTO CEROM1
    MOVLW b'01111001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

MINUTOS2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO CEROM2

CEROM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO UNOM2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo



UNOM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO DOSM2
    MOVLW b'00010000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00100001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

DOSM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO TRESM2
    MOVLW b'00110011'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000101'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01110001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo


TRESM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO CUATROM2
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo

CUATROM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO CINCOM2
    MOVLW b'01111000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

CINCOM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO SEISM2
    MOVLW b'01111001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

SEISM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO SIETEM2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01000001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


SIETEM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO OCHOM2
    MOVLW b'01000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01111111'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00001000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


OCHOM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO NUEVEM2
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo


NUEVEM2
    BTFSC PORTA,3
    GOTO CEROM2
    MOVLW b'00110001'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'01001001'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00111110'
    MOVWF PORTB 
    CALL retardo
    MOVLW b'00000000'
    MOVWF PORTB
    CALL retardo

retardo  
decfsz Delay1,1     
goto  retardo   
decfsz Delay2,1
goto retardo
return

END
```

Comment: The 18F4550 has 4 timers/counters.  It would be better if you used one of them for the delay loop.  http://roberthall.net/PIC18F4550_Timers